# How do I include a JCL PDS Library in a REXX Program

Tags: mainframe, jcl, rexx, ispf

I am writing a Rexx program to automate sequential submission of jobs.
    The Code is like :

```
/*REXX*/
  Address ISPEXEC "LIBDEF ISPPLIB DATASET ID('XXX.YYY.PANELS')
  Address ISPEXEC "LIBDEF ISPMLIB DATASET ID('XXX.YYYY.JCLLIB')
  isf_rc=ISFACALLS('ON')

  Addres ISPEXEC "Display Panel(Panel1)"
  if rc<>0 then do 
     say isf_rc
  end
  if zcmd==1 then do /*zcmd is a variable defined in the Panel to capture user input*/
     Address TSO "SUBMIT (JCLMEM01)"
  end
```

The error message is Dataset JCLMEM01 not found .

How do I solve this error?

Comment: are you really allocating the JCL-Library to the ispf-message library ??? or is that a copy mistake. Also please indented the code to make it easy for people to read. I will do it this time.

Answer (score 1):

When posting messages, you need to include the full text with the message reference. Please add that (paste it from from emulator) to your question.

The `TSO SUBMIT` command (when not used from within the `ISPF Editor`) requires a `dataset`. A `PDS Member` is not a dataset. The PDS-and-Member-together do count as a dataset.

```
"SUBMIT XXX.YYYY.JCLLIB(JCLMEM01)"
```

You should always look up any messages you get. That'll get you there 99% of the time. In Rexx, also look at how to use `Trace`.